# How many sheets for the Green function?

Tags: mathematical-physics

The Hamiltonian of a particle in a 1D potential is

$$H = H_0 + V(x) .  $$

Here $H_0 = p^2/2m$ is the free part.  It is known that the Green function

$$ G_0(E) = \frac{1}{E - H_0 } $$

has a cut long the positive real axis, but **can be analytically continued into a single-valued function on a 2-sheet Riemann surface**.

The question is, is it also the case for the Green function

$$ G(E) = \frac{1}{E - H } $$
 of $H $?

Answer (score 0):

Let the state $|\psi'\rangle = |\psi\rangle + V|\psi'\rangle$, where $V$ is the perturbing or potential that induces scattering. We are looking at a process that propagates a scattering influence, and propose the Green's function $(E - H)G = 1$ for $G = G(x,x')$. We can then see
$$
(H' - E)|\psi'\rangle =  (H' - E - V)|\psi'\rangle + (E - H)GV|\psi'\rangle
$$
$$
(E - E)(|\psi'\rangle - GV|\psi'\rangle) = (H - E)|\psi\rangle = 0
$$
makes this consistent. The relevant term is $ |\psi'\rangle - GV|\psi'\rangle$ that gives the scattered portion of the wave $|\phi\rangle = |\psi'\rangle - |\psi\rangle$ $ = GV|\psi'\rangle$. The transition matrix is then found by the expansion of the state $|\psi'\rangle$
$$
|\psi'\rangle = (1 + GV + GVGV + \dots)|\psi\rangle = (1 - GV)^{-1}|\psi\rangle
$$
so the transition matrix 
$$
T = \langle\psi|T|\psi\rangle = \langle\psi|V|\psi'\rangle = \langle\psi|V(1 - GV)^{-1}|\psi\rangle.
$$ 
This is also the basis for the Lippman-Schwinger equation that has
$$
|\psi'\rangle = V(1 - GV)^{-1}|\psi\rangle
$$

Comment: This did not answer the question.